# Can my Google Docs app be secured?

Tags: security, google-drive

I have sensitive information in my Google Docs.

I enabled two-step verification with my Google account; but just noticed that Google DOCS on my phone doesn't require any type of PIN number or password when I open it.  Is there a way to secure this app?

NOTE:  I also have a PIN number that must be entered after swipe.

Comment: So you're saying that your lock screen has a PIN? If Google Docs doesn't have a separate one, then that might be the best you can do. I'm not sure if there is an app that let's you control access to individual apps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is an app locker app. There are many app lockers in Play Store. Just, search. I'd recommend [Smart App Protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free) (I use its pro version which is great). Use it to lock Google Docs app.